# What is the order of importance of the pc components to be able to sculpt with really many polygons in blender?

Tags: sculpting

I refer to RAM, GPU, CPU, I want to know which is the most important component to invest more in that than in the rest, I want to sculpt fluidly since that's more fun.

Comment: If what you want is to sculpt invest first in Zbrush.

Answer (score 1):

CPU(most important to frequency) and RAM(not that relative).

Yet, Blender is open source application, and it might not be a really good one to do specialize job like sculpting.

The things you referred are not the most important thing in *fluidly sculpting*. Most of the time, a **good algorithm** and **code structure** will make a huge difference. And those **good** thing is not likely include in Blender since there is too many aspect Blender need to care about, and there is not that much resources Blender Foundation can use to develop it.

If you really need and want to have a good experiences in sculpting, try some specialized application, *e.g.* **ZBrush**

Comment: People are paid to develop blender, where do you think blender foundation donations go? Blender can't afford many developers though as they are reliant on donations/sponsorship. However you are right in that the most cost effective way to get really high poly sculpting is to buy zbrush.

Comment: @Sazerac My bad, didn't think when I type the word down. Thanks for the correction.